# Domain pointing to openvpn admin page (ubuntu 18.04 server)

Tags: ssl, openvpn, domain, ubuntu-18.04

I have a domain ***ns3245555.ip-163-131-175.eu*** which points to our website running on Apache2.

I also started Openvpn access server and I can reach it by going to the server's ip address and adding a port number "943" and "/admin" like so :

```
https://165.131.173.123:943/admin/
```

I want to install TLS(SSL) certificate for the Openvpn admin page and TLS certificates only work when a FQDN name for a OpenVPN Access Server is used.

How do I make our domain `ns3245555.ip-163-131-175.eu` point to `https://165.131.173.123:943/admin/` ?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: That isn't your domain name, it's OVH's, and they just assign it to your server while you are paying for it as a temporary name. It's expected that you will use your own domain name for anything significant.

Comment: I see. So I need to buy one and then point it to https://165.131.173.123:943/admin/   is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, you need to have a domain name and point that to the IP address. Then you can create a certificate and use that for <yourdomain>:943/admin.

Comment: Thanks @Fredrik. 

However, I found out that if one is using EasyRSA as a certificate authority then fully qualified domain name (fqdn) is not needed.